Help in understanding this part of Mansfield / Weitkamp
I am trying to read Effective Descriptive Set Theory by Mansfield and Weitkamp (self-study only so please bear with me ... am a beginner in this area).
I need help in understanding Example 1.24 of the book, which states that every set of reals that is definable by a $\Sigma_1$ formula of set theory is $\Sigma_2^1$.
The example defines $\mathcal{A}$ as a well-founded model of the extensionality axiom. A real $\alpha$ is said to have a copy in $\mathcal{A}$ iff $\alpha$ is in the unique transitive collapse of $\mathcal{A}$, i.e. $\alpha = \pi(\hat{\alpha})$ where $\pi$ is the function used in the transitive collapse, and $\hat{\alpha} \in \mathcal{A}$, i.e. $\hat{\alpha}$ is the name for $\alpha$ in $\mathcal{A}$.
Let the universe of $\mathcal{A}$ be $\omega$. In Lemma 1.25, the book then defines a function $F$ as:
$$
\begin{align*}
F(k) = n  \leftrightarrow & \exists s[\text{$s$ is a sequence $\langle s_0,...,s_k \rangle$ of integers} \\ & \quad \quad \text{so that $s_k=n$, $s_0=0$ and $\forall i < k, \mathcal{A} \models s_{i+1} = s_i+1$]}
\end{align*}
$$
Now, the proof of the lemma claims that $F(k)$ is the $k$th integer of $\mathcal{A}$, so that
$$
\begin{align*} 
\alpha \in \mathcal{A} \leftrightarrow &\text{there is an integer $n$ which names $\alpha$} \\ \leftrightarrow &\exists n\text{[$\mathcal{A} \models$ ($n$ is a function of integers into integers}) \\ & \text{$\quad \wedge (\forall k,l(\alpha(k)=l \leftrightarrow \mathcal{A} \models n(F(k)) = F(l))$]}
\end{align*}
$$
I would need help in understanding the following.

What does it mean for $\hat{\alpha} \in \mathcal{A}$ to be a "name" for $\alpha \in \mathcal{A}$ so that $\alpha=\pi(\hat{\alpha})$ ?
How to understand $s_{i+1} = s_i+1$ in the definition of $F(k)$ ? I am guessing this is not equivalent to the standard $+1$ operation in $\mathbb{N}$ ...
How should I understand $\text{[$\mathcal{A} \models$ $n$ is a function of integers into integers}]$ ? I know that the reals can be represented as functions of integers to integers but in this case, we are saying that $n$ (which is an integer in $\mathcal{A}$) is a function of integers to integers

Any help is really really appreciated.

The definition of "$\alpha$ has a copy in $\mathcal A$" should be "there exists an $\hat\alpha\in\mathcal A$ such that $\pi(\hat\alpha)=\alpha$." Such an $\hat\alpha$ is apparently called both a copy of $\alpha$ and a name of $\alpha$ in $\mathcal A$.
As for your second and third questions, notice that the formulas you're worried about, $s_{i+1}=s_1+1$ and "$n$ is a function",  are in the scope of $\mathcal A\models$. So all set-theoretic notions in these formulas, like $+$ and "function", are to be interpreted in $\mathcal A$. In particular, although all elements of $\mathcal A$ are natural numbers in the usual sense, many are not natural numbers in the sense of $\mathcal A$, and some are functions in the sense of $\mathcal A$..

thank you ! just to ask one more little thing, from the definition can $n$ serve as a copy for several distinct reals in $\mathcal{N}$ ?

@LinkL No, because the trnsitive-collapse function $\pi$ is an isomorphism, in particular it's one-to-one.

thanks again for this, but one final clarification ... from what I understand, the reals are $\alpha \in \mathcal{N}$ (i.e. the Baire space), and $\mathcal{N}$ is uncountable but the model $\mathcal{A}$ in Lemma 1.25 is countable, so I thought that several reals from the uncountable space $\mathcal{N}$ may be mapped to a single copy $n \in \mathcal{A}$ as $\mathcal{A}$ is countable (i.e. $n \in \mathcal{A}$ would be something like an equivalence class over $\mathcal{N}$). am I missing something re isomorphism ?

@LinkL A countable $\mathcal A$ has names for only countably many reals. Most reals don't have copies in $\mathcal A$.
